# Matlab Matrix of Matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am making a advanced game in MATLAB for a class. I coded a map generator and room generator. Both are matrices in any [x,y] size. I need to save the room matrices into the map matrix. I tried already and keep on getting the error message: "Unable to perform assignment because the left and right sides have a different number of elements." **I concluded that the problem is the map matrix isn't initialized to hold matrices. But how would I initialize a matrix of matrices?**

My code:
The class definition and constructor

```
classdef map < handle
    %map superclass map to save all map and room info
    %   Generates and saves map info and then calls upon the room class to
    %   generate rooms and saves produced rooms into a grid of rooms that
    %   coorelates with the map grid it produces itself.

    properties
        grid; %Saves where rooms are
        grid_rooms; %Saves layout of room
        level; %Level of map, higher level results in more rooms generated
    end
    
    methods
        function obj = map(xSize, ySize, level)
            %Constructor Construct an instance of this class
            %   Initializes the map obj properties
            obj.grid = zeros([xSize, ySize]);
            obj.grid
            obj.grid_rooms = zeros([xSize, ySize]); %PROBLEM: CANNOT SAVE ROOMS INTO grid_rooms
            obj.grid_rooms
            obj.level = level;
            obj.map_gen();
        end
```

The function to generate and save rooms:

```
        function load_room(obj, pos)
            %load_room Loads room using room_gen
            %
            %   Takes the map obj.grid_room and inputted position of the
            %   room to load. Procedes to use the room_gen function from
            %   room obj. The loaded room is then saved back into the map
            %   obj.grid_room(pos).
            obj.grid_rooms(pos) = room_gen(room(obj.grid, pos, obj.level), 8, 8);
        end
```

The room_gen function just produces a grid of numbers. The value zero represents empty space while the value negative one represents a wall. An example of the room_gen result is seen below.

```
roomGrid =

    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
    -1     0     0     0     0     0     0    -1
    -1     0     0     0     0     0     0    -1
    -1     0     0     0     0     0     0    -1
    -1     0     0     0     0     0     0    -1
    -1     0     0     0     0     0     0    -1
    -1     0     0     0     0     0     0    -1
    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
```

Basically to reiterate the issue, I need to be able to the roomGrid above, into map obj.grid_rooms. The problem is I don't know how to initialize the obj.grid_rooms to be able to save it. I tried multiple random ways but they did not work. Please help.

Sorry ahead of time for the confusing explanation :).

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html

Comment: Thank you! You are a god send. I don't know how I didn't find out about cells. The rooms are being saved now :).